# Web-scraping with PowerShell Issue: My code won't pull in the needed information. Why?

Tags: powershell, web-scraping

Web-scraping with PowerShell Issue: My code won't pull in the needed information. Why?

My code up to this point will pull the correct information. the info it shows is:

```
Here is a list of the top 10 results:

href                                    
----                                    
/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-windows        
/Hack-with-Github/Windows               
/felixrieseberg/windows95               
/boxcutter/windows                      
/HostsTools/Windows                     
/chef-boneyard/windows                  
/Sycnex/Windows10Debloater              
/microsoft/terminal                     
/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit
/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples
```

After the needed info comes into the PowerShell terminal. I'm trying to pull in a new web scrape but it won't work.

Here is my PowerShell code:

```
 $choice = Read-Host "Type number here"
    Write-Host ""
    if ([string]1 -eq $choice )

    {
    $add = Read-Host "Add an above repo here"
    $url2 = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com' + $add + '/master/README.md'
    $contributors2 = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url2 -UseBasicParsing
    $contributors2.Links| Where-Object "pre" | Select-Object innerText | Out-String
    Write-Output $output2

    }
```

And the info I'm trying to grab is:

```
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">## Windows

Awesome tools to play with Windows!

List of tools used for exploiting Windows:

- **[Exploitation](https://github.com/hacksysteam/Exploitation)** : Windows Software Exploitation
- **[hacking-team-windows-kernel-lpe](https://github.com/vlad902/hacking-team-windows-kernel-lpe)** : Previously-0day exploit from the Hacking Team leak, written by Eugene Ching/Qavar.
- **[mimikatz](https://github.com/gentilkiwi/mimikatz)** : A little tool to play with Windows security - extract plaintexts passwords, hash, PIN code and kerberos tickets from memory.
- **[Pazuzu](https://github.com/BorjaMerino/Pazuzu)** : Reflective DLL to run binaries from memory
- **[Potato](https://github.com/foxglovesec/Potato)** : Privilege Escalation on Windows 7,8,10, Server 2008, Server 2012
- **[UACME](https://github.com/hfiref0x/UACME)** : Defeating Windows User Account Control
- **[Windows-Exploit-Suggester](https://github.com/GDSSecurity/Windows-Exploit-Suggester)** : This tool compares a targets patch levels against the Microsoft vulnerability database in order to detect potential missing patches on the target. It also notifies the user if there are public exploits and Metasploit modules available for the missing bulletins.

### Misc

- **[afot](https://github.com/harris21/afot)** : Automation Forensics Tool for Windows
- **[Invoke-LoginPrompt](https://github.com/enigma0x3/Invoke-LoginPrompt)** : Invokes a Windows Security Login Prompt and outputs the clear text password
- **[PowerShellArsenal](https://github.com/mattifestation/PowerShellArsenal)** : A PowerShell Module Dedicated to Reverse Engineering
- **[Winpayloads](https://github.com/nccgroup/Winpayloads)** : Undetectable Windows Payload Generation

### PowerShell

- **[BloodHound](https://github.com/adaptivethreat/BloodHound)** : Six Degrees of Domain Admin
- **[Empire](https://github.com/adaptivethreat/Empire)** : Empire is a PowerShell and Python post-exploitation agent
- **[Generate-Macro](https://github.com/enigma0x3/Generate-Macro)** : Powershell script will generate a malicious Microsoft Office document with a specified payload and persistence method
- **[Invoke-AltDSBackdoor](https://github.com/enigma0x3/Invoke-AltDSBackdoor)** : This script will obtain persistence on a Windows 7+ machine under both Standard and Administrative accounts by using two Alternate Data Streams
- **[Old-Powershell-payload-Excel-Delivery](https://github.com/enigma0x3/Old-Powershell-payload-Excel-Delivery)** : This version touches disk for registry persistence
- **[PSRecon](https://github.com/gfoss/PSRecon)** : PSRecon gathers data from a remote Windows host using PowerShell (v2 or later), organizes the data into folders, hashes all extracted data, hashes PowerShell and various system properties, and sends the data off to the security team
- **[PowerShell-Suite](https://github.com/FuzzySecurity/PowerShell-Suite)** : Some useful scripts in powershell
- **[PowerSploit](https://github.com/PowerShellMafia/PowerSploit)** : A PowerShell Post-Exploitation Framework
- **[PowerTools](https://github.com/PowerShellEmpire/PowerTools)** : A collection of PowerShell projects with a focus on offensive operations
- **[Powershell-C2](https://github.com/enigma0x3/Powershell-C2)** : A PowerShell script to maintain persistance on a Windows machine
- **[Powershell-Payload-Excel-Delivery](https://github.com/enigma0x3/Powershell-Payload-Excel-Delivery)** : Uses Invoke-Shellcode to execute a payload and persist on the system
- **[mimikittenz](https://github.com/putterpanda/mimikittenz)** : A post-exploitation powershell tool for extracting juicy info from memory.

</pre>
```

Why won't my code pull in this Github documentation?

Comment: Where does`$output2` come from?

Comment: Are you getting a 404 error?  This may occur if the page is only accessible if you you are logged in to the site.

Comment: It can be accessed in a terminal web-scraper when I use python inside a Linux bash terminal. I'm trying to make a windows version and learn PowerShell at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
$contributors2.Links| Where-Object "pre" | Select-Object innerText | Out-String
```

with:

```
$contributors2.Content
```

It does like your code is missing a few things - [as per @Theo's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo), it's not clear where `$output2` is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my issue. I needed to change the `$contributors2` qualifier from Links to RawContent.

Here is the code change:

```
    $choice = Read-Host "Type number here"
    Write-Host ""
    if ([string]1 -eq $choice )

    {
    $add = Read-Host "Add an above repo here"
    $url2 = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com' + $add + '/master/README.md'
    $contributors2 = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url2 -UseBasicParsing
    $contributors2.RawContent | Out-String
    Write-Output $output

    }
```

It now pulls in the desired web-scrape.